# onCreateContextMenu return wrong view

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and a GridView in my main activity. both are registered for the same ContextMenu. everything was working fine for both and while I was working on the custom adaptor of the GridView and testing, I found that the RecyclerView is returning a wrong view.
I noticed that when I long press the first view it return the first view as normal, but when long press every next view returns the previous view.
I tried to re-check the history of most of the files I was working on but everything is ok. also tried to invalidate cash and restart but no luck.
this is my onCreateContextMenu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.links_listview) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        tTitle = info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.linkTitle);
        tText = info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.linkText);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(tTitle.getText().toString());
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.horizontal_recycler) {
        tTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.linkTitle);
        tText = v.findViewById(R.id.linkText);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(tTitle.getText().toString());
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to test a very old back up version of my app and I got the same problem, although I'm 100% sure it was working fine when I backed it up. I guess it might be something wrong with the new update of Android Studio 3.3.2 .... but still, how can I solve it?

Comment: I downgraded to Android Studio 3.2 and Gradle 4.6 but the problem still persist. Please help.